# How to connect Azure Database for MySQL flexible server in Azure SQL Server Database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-database-mysql

I am trying to set up a connection between Azure MySQL flexible server and Azure SQL database mainly to read data from MySQL and store it in the SQL Server periodically (multiple times a day).

I was thinking of creating a stored procedure inside my SQL Server database; however, I cannot seem to get a connection from the SQL Server into the MySQL database.
I know with ODBC you can connect MySQL to on-prem SQL Server, but unfortunately, there is nothing I have found for the same functionality for Azure SQL Server.

Has anyone done this? Is this possible?

I have tried to set up an ODBC connection, but it did not work as the SQL Server is on Azure.

I tried setting up a linked server inside SQL Server straight to MySQL, but it doesn't seem possible as the SQL Server is not on-prem.

I tried creating external database objects based on the following [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-query-getting-started-vertical?view=azuresql#create-database-objects).

With all these approaches, my expectation was to surface the MySQL tables from Azure SQL Server/SSMS.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Try using [MySQL Workbench](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/connect-workbench).

Comment: you can try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/migration-guides/database/mysql-to-sql-database-guide?view=azuresql

Comment: @AmareswarapuBhavani this would work if i needed to migrate once, however, my issue is that I would need to copy the data over quite regularly (every 15 minutes or so)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had to create an Azure Function App that contains a Timer function that reads the data from the MySQL data and pushes it to SQL Server every 15 minutes (as were the requirements).

Thank you for everyone for commenting.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

MySql Workbench is the perfect option for connecting the azure database for mysql.
for that we need to create flexible server in azure portal. I created flexible server in azure portal.

Image for reference:

[image]

I created database in flexible server by clicking add in in database option. it crated successfully.
Image for refence:

[image]

I installed MySQL Workbench in my local system.
you can get your required fields to connect the server in connect tab.
Image for reference:

[image]

I connected to the server by filling required fields.
Image for reference:

[image]

Click on ok. It connected successfully.
Image for reference:

[image]

AFAIK Export the data from Azure mysql flexible server in the form of sql script through MySQL work bench and import that file in Azure sql database through SSMS.  IN this we can write data into Azure Sql database.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can use [Data-in replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/concepts-data-in-replication).